# Adjusting Code for the Month

Tags: vba, excel

Good Morning,

I have a code that pulls quarterly reports to run the macro, however I am running into an issue with changing the defined month. In the report used for the macro it contains the month and is subject to change. how do I adjust my code to switch the month.

```
 Dim Quarter As String
 Dim Month As String
 Dim SIFile As String
 Dim SIData As String
 Dim SiName As String
 Dim FiName As String
 Dim MyQtr As String
 'Defining the worksheet variables and the worksheet name
 Sheets("Summary").Select
 Range("X4").Select
 Quarter = Range("X4").Value
 MyQtr = Range("AA4").Value

 Range("Z4").Select
 Month = Range("Z4").Value

 SIFile = Quarter & "_si_allocation_audit__mar__6_decimal_detail_sjmc.txt"
 SiName = Quarter & "_si_allocation_audit__mar__"
```

Comment: there is CLEARLY a hardcoded value in there. do you want to change that? then do it. however, having hardcoded values for something that clearly changes is pretty bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming mar is the month and that the value is coming from Z4 and is already abbreviated then you would hold in a variable (not called Month as that is a function) and concatenate into the string for your file etc.

```
Dim monthAbbr As String
monthAbbr = Range("Z4").Value
SIFile = Quarter & "_si_allocation_audit__" & monthAbbr &  "__6_decimal_detail_sjmc.txt"
```

Comment: yes mars is the month, thanks I will test this out now